# I want to set metatitle like PRODUCT NAME + BRANDS .How can i do this?

Tags: opencart, meta-title

In opencart I want to update metatitle for product like this :  PRODUCT NAME + BRANDS .Does anybody know a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to Add Meta Title + Brand

> Blockquote

Either you will add meta title and brand in admin side of product section.
On Product section have meta title field.

OR,
Change code on catalog/controller/product.php file.

Here is the code for it.

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
```

You will Change code with EG.

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title'] ." | ". $manufacturer_info['name']);
```

Comment: I guess this is for seting product title but i want META  title to be title + brand, and also in database metatitle wil be updated like this

Comment: $this->document->setTitle() function display name of product title.